# My sprite node will not show up in my scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've created an SKScene and used addChild to place my SKSpriteNode in the scene. It indicates that the node is there in the bottom right but There is no sprite to be seen. Everything seems to look right but no results. My scene.scaleMode is .aspectFill, I've made sure the SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "GreenBlock") is correct. I've looked over it so many times but it makes no sense to me why it won't show on screen...

It's such a simple task. I've seen others do the exact same and it works. I've tried everything I can think of...

My View Controller

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GreenSnakeController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = SKView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let SKView = self.view as! SKView? {
            let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)

            SKView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            SKView.showsFPS = true
            SKView.showsNodeCount = true
            scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
            SKView.presentScene(scene)
        }

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

My Game Scene class

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var snakeBlock: SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        layoutScene()
    }

    func layoutScene() {
        backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.262745098, green: 0.262745098, blue: 0.262745098, alpha: 1)

        snakeBlock = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "GreenBlock")
        snakeBlock.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width/8.0, height: frame.size.width/8.0)
        snakeBlock.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        addChild(snakeBlock)
    }
}
```

I expect something to show up on screen and although it indicates that there are two nodes, I see nothing but the scene that is the first node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't start this project as a game project so there was no GameScene.sks file and the scene anchor point was not set to the center of the view. To do this I had to set it in the didMove function in my GameScene class like such -

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        layoutScene()
        scene?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }


    override func loadView() {
        self.view = SKView()
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Just by changing the `viewDidLoad()` recommended by Apple it worked for me when I tried it. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: If I don't add
    override func loadView() {
        self.view = SKView()
    }
The app crashes. I tried this code with the override loadView in it and all my nodes were gone : /

Comment: This is my output when I added an image for the "greenBlock" https://imgur.com/niRZu0Y

Comment: If you change the code in the GameViewController, it should present your scene

Comment: If it is still not showing up you have a problem, I would suggest checking the GameViewController is set as the initial view.

Comment: It's not the initial view

Comment: If it's not the initial view how are you running the code?

Comment: This is when the viewdidload is edited:  imgur.com/db0Qcwe

Comment: My initial view is the apps main purpose but the second view is reached by clicking the snake tab on the bottom tab bar. It will be a simple snake game if I can get this far.

Comment: If you have changed your code to the answer and it still isn't working, are you sure the SnakeViewController is reached? Insert a print statement in the didmovetoview because there is no problem with the example I created using you code.

Comment: If you want to look at my plain example : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6cv044vyjiugoks/AAAtAhOy009G5VaQpdwAe-2aa?dl=0

Comment: It's definitely being reached because I get the scene with my stats just no greenBlock. The initial view is working fine.

Comment: So I found out that if I use Ints like this in my size and position, "snakeBlock.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        snakeBlock.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)" the block shows up... but why?? This is really bizarre right? Here's the result https://imgur.com/ZnhmCfM

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate you trying to figure this out but I figured out my dumb error finally :p